# How long does it take for a Google Marketplace App to be reviewed?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We submitted our application over a month ago and never received a confirmation or any feedback since.  How long does it normally take for an App to be reviewed?

The application was submitted under:  dylan@argon.io

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor account support question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact the vendor directly for questions related to your specific account.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ken!  Google pointed this out as a possible place to get support:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-marketplace-dev-community/3N1fiRIIFJg, and also mentioned: https://plus.google.com/communities/116649587096405255956.  I'm assuming I could inquire on the G+ page instead?

Comment: well you can get support here in the sense that we can help you with your code, not in the sense we replace Google's support. We have no way to track your App, we're in no way Google :P

Comment: That's for *programming* support, not specific account related support. We can help with programming for the marketplace, but this question is about *your own specific account*, and we can't help with that type of issue here. Because a third-party vendor suggests this as a source for support does not mean *all questions* can be asked here. Questions still have to meet this site's guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did submit a request as explained in the point 7, right?

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing

They only contact you if something is wrong with your app.

If everything is fine, your app should appear in the listing within few days.

Comment: Indeed!  We're going to resubmit to see if that helps.  Thanks for the input.